# 4.6.9 upgrade fails - DB_Error:already exists -5

Tags: drupal, upgrade, database, error

I've attached a screenshot of the error I get when trying to upgrade from 4.6.8 to 4.6.9

I have the rest of the trace, but not sure if I should post all of it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: have you taken an Backup before upgrading - if so, please check the old DB civicrm_country table and verify that you have "Saint Barthelemy" country do exist or not - If it has then do delete it and run the upgrade again

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken an Backup before upgrading - if so, please check the old DB civicrm_country table and verify that you have "Saint Barthelemy" country do exist or not - If it has then do delete it and run the upgrade again